# php update value from an array except one

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want update my database from an array except one value from  `$_POST`

```
$_POST['value'] = 'b';
$array = array('a','ab','b','bb','c','cc');
//insert 'a','ab','bb','c','cc' except $_POST['value'] 'b'
mysql_query("UPDATE core SET list='".$newarray."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."' ");
```

How do I do? use `preg_replace` remove the `$_POST['value']` --> difficulty judge the comma ','

or advanced `mysql query` skill?

Comment: Set $_POST['value'] after update?

Comment: $_POST['value'] = 'b';
$array = array('a','ab','b','bb','c','cc');
I don't understand this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly...

```
$newarray = implode( ',', array_diff( $array, array( $_POST[ 'value' ] ) ) );

// $newarray == "a,ab,bb,c,cc"
```

Comment: Mind that this answer does no escaping (mysql_real_escape) of the array elements, so $array may only include database-safe values ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you need to filter by array value

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($value) {
  // you need to return a boolean value which tells
  // whether to include this element or not
  return $value != 'b';
});
$fields = implode(', ', $filtered);
mysql_query("UPDATE core SET list='".$fields."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."' ");
```

Or if you need to filter by array keys

```
$keys = array('...'); // list here allowed keys
$filtered = array_merge(array_combine($keys, $keys), $_POST);
$fields = implode(', ', $filtered);
mysql_query("UPDATE core SET list='".$fields."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = $array;
$key = array_search($_POST['value'], $newarray);

if ($key !== false)
{
   unset($newarray[$key]);
}
```

Comment: Note: This only removes the first matched item.